# Modify the Arabic font size in Latex document

Tags: xetex, fontspec, arabxetex

I need a help to modify the Arabic font size in this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier} % math font
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tablists}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}% pour arabe
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{titlesec}





\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=algeria]{arabic}
%\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Traditional Arabic}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setsansfont[Mapping=text-text]{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\sectcolor[Color=sectcolor,Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\subsectcolor[Color=subsectcolor,Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\subbsectcolor[Color=subbsectcolor,Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Color=textcolor,Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}


\usepackage[Lenny ]{fncychap}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section} -\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section} -\arabic{subsubsection}-\arabic{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
%\vspace*{-1mm}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0  pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}




%\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{darkred}{#1}}
\newtheorem{exo}{تمرين}
\newtheorem{definition}{تعريف}
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}
\newtheorem{proprieties}{خواص}
\newtheorem{application}{تطبيق}
\newtheorem{remark}{ملاحظة}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead {} % on efface l’entête
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{} % on efface le pied de page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\parindent 0pt

\begin{document}
\frontmatter




%\input{pageTitre}

\tableofcontents{}



\chapter{المصفوفات}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{المصفوفات}
%\newpage
\vspace*{-0.6cm}
\section{مفاهيم أولية}
\subsection{ المصفوفة }
\begin{definition}:
 نسمي مصفوفة كل جدول من الأعداد الحقيقية المرتبة على شكل $m$ سطر و $n$ عمود. الأعداد التي تكون المصفوفة تسمى عناصر (أو معاملات) المصفوفة. المصفوفة ذات $m$ سطر و $n$ عمود تدعى مصفوفة من الرتبة $(m,n)$ أو البعد $m\times n$. نرمز إلى مجموعة كل المصفوفات ذات البعد  $m\times n$ بالرمز $\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

  \end{definition}



\begin{thebibliography}{99}
   [1]
       من ويكيبيديا، الموسوعة الحرة
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try `[...,Scale=1.8]{Traditional Arabic}`?

Comment: Thanks touhami for ur respond, There is no change.

Comment: sorry, but did you try `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Color=textcolor,Script=Arabic,Scale=1.8]{Traditional Arabic}`? it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry Touhami, I don't see the difference, Can I obtain the size 16 for Arabic fonts and 14 for Latin  fonts (like in Microsoft word doc) in my latex document?

Comment: Can you make your example minimal (i.e., load *only* the packages needed to reproduce the problem) and replace the proprietary fonts with fonts found in TeX Live (e.g., Amiri for Arabic, and TeX Gyre Termes instead of Times New Roman)? That way more of us will be able to help you.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem with Amiri: @touhami’s solution works — unless the Traditional Arabic font is defective, but that would have come to light by now. However, `fontspec` warns that `sectcolor` and `textcolor` are bad color declarations (and since you haven’t loaded `xcolor` or used the first three of the new font families you’ve defined, it’s not clear what you’re trying to accomplish). You should fix such warnings before proceeding.